# Chrome Extension using DevTools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, chromium

I am trying to reuse a part of the Elements tab in DevTools in my own Chrome Extension.
Do I need to use the Chrome DevTools SDK http://code.google.com/p/chromedevtools/wiki/ChromeDevToolsSdk ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the Chrome DevTools SDK will not help for you. You can read chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow api [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_inspectedWindow.html). I wish it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the code for the elements panel tree view is not available in your chrome extension.

The SDK will not help you either.

You'll have to build the UI yourself.